# Partitions of the complete graph on $n$ vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for a necessary and sufficient condition on $n$ such that a partition of the edge set of the complete graph on $n$ vertices $K_n$, into 3-cycles is possible.

One easily acquired *necessary* condition on $n$ is the following:
i) $n \equiv 1,3 \mod6$.
Is this also *sufficient*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are. 
The partition you are looking for is called *Steiner triple system*. You can read the induction proof in: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/37b1/2768904bcd2f00873fd16c2a21a7bfa6e705.pdf.

Comment: Indeed. The Fifteen schoolgirls problem asks for a resolvable Steiner system and it seems to exist only for $n \equiv 3 \pmod{6}$.